# Is it allowed for a married woman cooks for her boss at work without husband's consent?

Tags: practical-islam

In Islam, is it allowed for a married woman to cook food for her ex boss at work if he ask her to, while her husband dont know about it? When the husband confronted her about the food,  she told him it is for her boss but not before he asked her. Is this correct or wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It is not permissible to use what the husband has provided to you out of his consent. If he is providing the food, the gas bills, the rent for the house etc., it is his property which cannot be used for someone else without his consent.

> Abu Umamah Al-Bahili said: "During a sermon of his in the year of the
>   Farewell Hajj, I heard the Messenger of Allah say: 'A woman is not to
>   spend anything from her husbands house without her husband's
>   permission.' They said: 'O Messenger of Allah! What about food?' He
>   said: 'That is our most virtuous wealth.'"
>
> <sub>[Jami` at-Tirmidhi 670](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/7/54)</sub>

And Allah knows Best